# pointer to pointer in linkedlist cannot preserve the pointer after every call from the main function. Why?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream>

#define print(x) std::cout<<x<<std::endl;

class Node
{
    public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node** head_ref;
public:
    LinkedList() :head_ref(NULL) {};



    void insertFront(int new_data)
    {
        Node* new_node = new Node();
        new_node->data = new_data;

        if(this->head_ref == NULL)
            this->head_ref = &new_node;
        else
        {
            new_node->next = *(this->head_ref);
            this->head_ref = &new_node;
        }
    }

    void PrintLinkedList()
    {
        Node* temp = (*(this->head_ref));
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            print(temp->data);
        }
        print("\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList a1;
    a1.insertFront(5);
    a1.insertFront(6);
    a1.insertFront(7);
    a1.PrintLinkedList();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

As you will see in the screenshots in the **watch1 tab** the `this->head_ref` preserves the location of the `Node*` but `Node*` i.e. `(*(this->head_ref))` doesn't preserve the location of the Node. I want to know what is causing this. Is it because `Node**` head_ref has no regulation in how the inside pointer points to the Node or is it a scope problem? The problem occurs each time right after the next function call happens and the debugger enters the `insertFront` function, the `Node*` becomes a free pointer pointing to nothing.

[First call screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCpfK.png)

[Second call screenshot before entering insertFront](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxpI4.png)

[Second call screenshot just after entering insertFront but a new Node object has not been made yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhWlQ.png)

Comment: You assign to `head_ref` the address of a local variable, `new_node`. Then the function returns, the local variable is destroyed, and `head_ref` ends up a dangling pointer; any attempt to use it later exhibits undefined behavior. Why did you make `head_ref` a `Node**`? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But the new_node is heap allocated for that purpose right? Or heap allocation too happens in the scope of class? (Yeah, I have already made the program with Node* head_ref and it works, I just wanted to test myself with a pointer to pointer.) And the problem  is when debugging the value doesn't get lost when it goes out of class (that's the confusing part), it gets lost when the debugger re-enters the insertFront function as you can see in the screenshots.

Comment: The `Node` object is allocated on the heap. But the `Node*` object named `new_node` is allocated on the stack. You have `head_ref` point to `new_node` and `new_node` point to the `Node` object. Then the function returns, `new_node` is gone, and there is no longer any connection between `head_ref` and the heap-allocated `Node`. `head_ref` points to some garbage value where `new_node` used to be, and `Node` on the heap is leaked as nothing points to it anymore.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik oh okay so this is how it is. Thank you, so when you assign a pointer the address location is on the stack and the value is on the heap? Is it right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. When you take the address of a local variable on the stack, the resulting pointer points to that variable on the stack, obviously. When you use `new` to allocate an object on the heap, the resulting pointer points to that object on the heap, obviously.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you very much, your second comment is the answer. I'm new to this so I forgot to format. Will do in upcoming engagements with the community.

Comment: You do not want `Node** head_ref`. Remove one asterisk and start from there. If you think you cannot manage it with one asterisk, ask a separate question and show where you are stuck.

Comment: @Yunnosch Ok I have formatted the question. My own comments are frozen so can't be formatted. I also added the working code with credits to the one who answered. I guess all is fine now?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is provided by @IgorTandetnik in the comments.

> The `Node` object is allocated on the heap. But the `Node*` object named `new_node` is allocated on the stack. You have `head_ref` point to `new_node` and `new_node` point to the `Node` object. Then the function returns, `new_node` is gone, and there is no longer any connection between `head_ref` and the heap-allocated Node. `head_ref` points to some garbage value where `new_node` used to be, and `Node` on the heap is leaked as nothing points to it anymore.

I have changed the code accordingly by using `Node* head_ref` which will refer to a heap allocated `Node` instead of the `new_node`pointer which goes out of scope.

```
#include<iostream>
#define print(x) std::cout<<x<<std::endl;

class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node* head_ref;
public:
    LinkedList() :head_ref(NULL) {};

    void insertFront(int new_data)
    {
        Node* new_node = new Node();
        new_node->data = new_data;

        if(this->head_ref == NULL)
            this->head_ref = new_node;
        else
        {
            new_node->next = this->head_ref;
            this->head_ref = new_node;
        }
    }

    void PrintLinkedList()
    {
        Node* temp = this->head_ref;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            print(temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        print(temp->data);
        print("\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList a1;
    a1.insertFront(5);
    a1.insertFront(6);
    a1.insertFront(7);
    a1.PrintLinkedList();
    
    std::cin.get();
}
```